# Peewee How do i call post_delete signal for dependencies?

Tags: foreign-keys, hook, peewee, cascading-deletes

I see peewee has signal http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#signals

But it works only with `delete_instance()`.

> For what I hope are obvious reasons, Peewee signals do not work when
>   you use the Model.insert(), Model.update(), or Model.delete() methods.
>   These methods generate queries that execute beyond the scope of the
>   ORM, and the ORM does not know about which model instances might or
>   might not be affected when the query executes.
>
> Signals work by hooking into the higher-level peewee APIs like
>   Model.save() and Model.delete_instance(), where the affected model
>   instance is known ahead of time.

So, how do i use signal on records which are dependencies since it use `delete()` on dependencies?

```
def delete_instance(self, recursive=False, delete_nullable=False):
        if recursive:
            dependencies = self.dependencies(delete_nullable)
            for query, fk in reversed(list(dependencies)):
                model = fk.model
                if fk.null and not delete_nullable:
                    model.update(**{fk.name: None}).where(query).execute()
                else:
                    model.delete().where(query).execute()
        return type(self).delete().where(self._pk_expr()).execute()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't, because recursive deletes are implemented using queries of the form:

```
DELETE FROM ... WHERE foreign_key_id = X
```

e.g., consider you have a user and they have created 1000 tweets. The tweet.user_id points to the user.id. When you delete that user, peewee issues 2 queries:

```
DELETE FROM tweets WHERE user_id = 123
DELETE FROM users WHERE id = 123
```

If it were to call `delete_instance()` you would end up issuing 1001 queries instead. So it is hopefully quite clear why it is implemented in this way.

I'd suggest that if you're deleting rows *and* need to perform some kind of cleanup on related rows, that you may be better off doing soft-deletes (e.g., setting a `status=DELETED`). Then do the processing of any relations outside of the signals API.